# get array, separate comma separated values and then recreate array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
[
["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap), Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
]
```

You'll notice that the 2nd lines of the array's second value has a value separated by a comma. I want to recreate the array like so.

```
[
["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"],
["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
const media = [ 
["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap), Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
];

var filteredArray = media.filter(function(r) {return r[1]})

filteredArray.forEach(function(value) {
   var fgh = value.slice(1);
   var cddd = [value.shift()]; // takes first part
   var ttt = fgh.toString()
   var str_array = ttt.split(', ');
      const array3 = cddd.concat(fgh);
     console.log(str_array);
});
```

I understand I need to use concat, split and then finally push it back but whatever I try I'm not getting the result I need so I need help and now I'm lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ensure your nested arrays will always have two elements then it's quite simple:

```js
const source = [ 
  ["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Basic)"],
  ["Cast", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap), Vehicle Graphics (Full Wrap)"],
  ["Polymeric", "Vehicle Graphics (Part Wrap)"]
];

// Flat map instructs that 
// the nested arrays we're going to return
// should be spread onto the root one
source.flatMap(([key, value]) => { // [key, value] de-structs the array passed as a parameter
  // Here we're getting an array of all possible values; 
  // if there's no ", " then we get a single element, 
  // otherwise we get the whole collection of values
  const values = value.split(', ') 

  // Now, for each of the individual values we create the key-value pairs
  return values.map(singleValue => [key, singleValue])
})
```

Yields:
[image]

- [Array destructuring JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/array-and-object-destructuring-in-javascript/)
- [Docs for flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. What if there were 17 elements?

Comment: The array containing the nested arrays can have an arbitrary length; no problem. But my solution forces that the nested arrays have length 2. Now you can have as many commas as you want and it'll work perfectly but the items need to be `['key', 'value1, value2, value3']`. The example given has 3 different values but it still is an array of length 2.

Comment: Thank you. I have 17 elements, it's number 17 that has the value I need to match. the code works if I have the value in number 1 but not anywhere else. Do I need to change this line also ```const fff =  values.map(singleValue => [key, singleValue])```?

Comment: Right. In that case you'd need to rewrite `source.flatMap(([key, value]) =>...` to `source.flatMap(fullArray => ...` and then process the full array in the same maner as I did for item at index 1

Comment: Hi, I really do appreciate your help but I've never even heard of the FlatMap function until now and I'm even more lost than before. I've marked your answer as completed because you answered it perfectly but the last comment has made me more confused than ever. Here's my https://jsfiddle.net/h7gorq6t/11/ and you're laugh how far I am away from completing the code. I started learning the basics to create a form from google sheets and I've gone into another world.

Comment: Let me get back at you after work. I'll provide a code pen going over what `flatMap` is and how it works. In the mean time you can start by reading on the web and the last two links I added to my answer as that's where I learned about them and how to use them.

Comment: Thank you, that will help a lot. I've been looking at it since your first post but the website examples I've found don't explain it enough in idiots terms. I've just found this site that seems better. https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/80-flatmap/

Comment: I have not forgotten about you. Here's a codepen going over `flatMap` with some detail https://codepen.io/NanoSpicer/pen/MWOqWyN